# Меню Bootstrap - как убирать элементы из navbar?

Tags: bootstrap

Доброго времени. Имеем стандартное меню. При изменении размеров пункты удаляются. И, в итоге - меню сворачивается.

Подскажите, возможно ли средствами Bootstrap сделать так, чтобы как только один пункт исчез, то появлялась иконка меню с этим пунктом, ну или всеми пунктами (как при малом размере экрана). А то получается: экран сузился и важный пункт ушел из поля зрения.

```html
<link href="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5/templates/adaptive/boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5/templates/adaptive/script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5/templates/adaptive/boostrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5/templates/adaptive/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-default menu-header" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>



      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">test</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link4</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link5</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link6</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link7</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link8</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link9</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg visible-md'><a href="#">Link10</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg'><a href="#">Link11</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg'><a href="#">Link12</a>
        </li>
        <li class='visible-xs visible-lg'><a href="#">eeeee13</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>





  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Из коробки" бутстрап делать так не умеет. Меню, которое появляется на узких экранах - изначально содержит весь набор пунктов, и, в зависимости от ширины экрана - либо отображается как сворачивающийся спойлер, либо как горизонтальный ряд в навбаре. Ваша задача требует выводить и то, и другое, но отображать отдельные пункты меню по-разному - либо в горизонтальном ряду, либо в спойлере.

При желании этого можно добиться с помощью javascript. При изменении размеров экрана - скрипт может проверять, какие элементы в горизонтальном ряду уже не помещаются - и выводить их в спойлере, вплоть до того, чтобы выводить там все элементы с первого до последнего. Но - это уже вряд ли будет связано с бутстраповским navbar - здесь вам потребуется писать собственный компонент.

Чтобы использовать бутстрап оптимальным образом - вы можете выполнить следующее:

1. Не держать в главном меню больше 5-8 ссылок;
2. Отрегулировать [$grid-float-breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), чтобы меню превращалось в спойлер ровно тогда, когда элементы перестают помещаться в ряд.